# MobX adding objects to an observable array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mobx, mobx-state-tree

### MobX objects to an observable array

I am unable to push an object into an observable array and have it be something that I can iterate on.

starting point (all data is via the console's log):

```
if (!self.selectedGlobalFilters) self.selectedGlobalFilters = observable([])
```

and taking in an object **filter.options01** as:

```
Proxy {Symbol(mobx administration): ObservableObjectAdministration$$1}
  [[Handler]]: Object
    [[Target]]: Object
      key: "status"
      value: "rejected"
```

...and then attempting a push

```
self.selectedGlobalFilters.push(filter.options01)
```

gives me:

```
[Proxy]
  0: Proxy
    [[Handler]]: Object
      [[Target]]: Object
        key: "status"
        value: "rejected"
```

then attempting to push another object **filter.options02** as:

```
Proxy {Symbol(mobx administration): ObservableObjectAdministration$$1}
  [[Handler]]: Object
    [[Target]]: Object
      key: "status"
      value: "done"


self.selectedGlobalFilters.push(filter.options02)
```

gives me:

```
[Proxy]
  0: Proxy
    [[Handler]]: Object
      [[Target]]: Object
        key: "status"
        value: "done"
```

So basically 2 issues here, one being that the second push overrides the first, but more-so I would like to have this data as such:

```
[{…}]
  0: 
    status: "rejected"
  1:
    status: "done"
```

**TLDR;**
**How would I go about achieving this?**
pushing an object into an observable array in a manner that can be iterated on...

slicing the array has no different effect on the output.

As always any and all direction is appreciated so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issues here is that you're only observing a variable and not Mapping the entire array!

```
@observable selectedGlobalFilters = [];

if (!this.selectedGlobalFilters.length) 
  this.selectedGlobalFilters.push(filter.options01)
```

..or

```
const gFilter = toJS(this.selectedGlobalFilters)
  this.selectedGlobalFilters = gFilter.push(filter.options01)
```

..if symptoms persist:-)